# Get parent of Xpath with certain class searching by child span

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath

I have here html like:

```
<div class="select-menu-item js-navigation-item">...</div>
<div class="select-menu-item js-navigation-item">...</div>
<div class="select-menu-item js-navigation-item">
    <svg ...></svg>

    <div class="select-menu-item-gravatar"></div>
    <div class="select-menu-item-text lh-condensed">
        <span class="select-menu-item-heading">
            the_username813
            <span class="description">Last name, First name</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to get the `<div class="select-menu-item js-navigation-item">` that includes the child span with `the_username813`.

I tried a few things that failed, like:

```
ipdb> element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(., 'the_username813')]/parent::div[contains(c
oncat(' ', @class, ' '), ' js-navigation-item ')]")
*** NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //span[contains(., 'the_username813')]/parent::div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' js-navigation-item ')]
```

How can I get this parent div element using Xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below `Xpath` expression and let me know the result:

```
//div[@class="select-menu-item js-navigation-item" and .//span[normalize-space(text())="the_username813"]]
```

Also note that `<div class="select-menu-item js-navigation-item">` is not a direct `parent`, but `ancestor` element, so you also might use

```
//span[normalize-space(text())="the_username813"]/ancestor::div[@class="select-menu-item js-navigation-item"]
```

Comment: yep, the first one was my goal. I didn't know you can use and there, thanks